# Approximation and modification of dictionary variables

Tags: python, approximation

I have a question
I have a dictionary called (plane) where I can call variables such as 'name' or 'speed'.

These values ​​give me this kind of output for example:

```
print(plane.get('name'))
print(plane.get('altitude'))
```

Output:

```
'name'= FLRDD8EFC
'speed'= 136.054323
```

My question is, how can I approximate the values ​​as follows?

```
'name'= DD8EFC (Always deleting the first three lines)
'speed'= 136.  (Approximate whole)
```

Thank you so much for your help!
G

Comment: plane is a class I suppose?

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus The question says it's a dictionary.

Comment: @abarnert, it is my bad. Forget dictionary have the attribute get...

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, how can I approximate the values ​​as follows?

You have to write the code explicitly.

---

> 'name'= DD8EFC (Always deleting the first three lines)

Fetch the string, then slice it:

```
name = plane.get('name')[3:]
print(f"'name' = {name}'")
```

However, the fact that you're using `get` rather than `[]` implies that you're expecting to handle the possibility that `name` doesn't exist in `plane`.

If that isn't a possibility, you should just use `[]`:

```
name = plane['name'][3:]
```

If it *is*, you'll need to provide a default that can be sliced:

```
name = plane.get('name', '')[3:]
```

---

> 'speed'= 136.  (Approximate whole)

It looks like you want to round to 0 fractional digits, but keep it a `float`? Call `round` with `0` digits on it. And again, either you don't need `get`, or you need a different default:

```
speed = round(plane['speed'], 0)
```

… or:

```
speed = round(plane.get('speed', 0.0), 0)
```

As for printing it: Python doesn't like to print a `.` after a `float` without also printing any fractional values. You can monkey with `format` fields, but it's probably simpler to just put the `.` in manually:

```
print(f"'speed': {speed}.")
```

Comment: Could UserDict be used to provide already modified results directly @abamert?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I suppose. Or just inherit directly from `dict`; there's no real need for the indirection here. But how would `__getitem__` decide what to do? Switch on the name? The type? If the OP specified some rules, we could build those rules, but I don't want to guess too wildly.

Comment: Thank you - I wrote a quick prototype; the 'switch' is fugly and brittle.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> plane.get('name')[3:]
'DD8EFC'
>>> round(plane.get('speed'))
136
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, possibly, subclass `collections.UserDict` (or maybe `dict` as @abamert suggested), and code some sort of switch/filter/formatter in the special method`__getitem__`:

something like this, maybe:

```
from collections import UserDict


class MyDict(UserDict):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'name':
            return self.data[key][3:]
        if key == 'speed':
            return round(self.data[key], 3)
        return self.data[key]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    mydata = MyDict({'name': 'ABCDEF', 'speed': 12.123456})
    print(mydata['name'], mydata['speed'])
```

#### output:

```
DEF 12.123
```

or subclassing `dict`:

```
class MyDict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'name':
            return self.get(key)[3:]
        if key == 'speed':
            return round(self.get(key), 3)
        return self[key]
```

**Disclaimer:** *This is more a proof of concept than anything; I do not recommend this approach; the 'switch' is ugly and could get out of hand as soon as the list of constraints grows a bit.*